# How do I capture toast notifications send from other processes in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, winapi, uwp, toast

Is there a way to detect toast notifications being shown by other apps in Windows 10?

Comment: Could you share a reference to that information please?

Comment: I have no idea how this question was marked as 'Too Broad```.  That's just stupid.  It's a very specific question, can you detect if another app throws a toast notification? I don't know the answer but I'm curious and if you can get this question any "less broad" then go for it. The powers that be on this site seriously need limited to some people.  This is ridiculously abused. The question is short, simple, and to the point, and IMO a very valid question. Profiles for the SOF powers that be marking it too broad also have no experience in UWP.

Answer (score 13):

you can listen to all notifications happening on windows via a notification listener: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener

Comment: Why was this down voted? At least state why it is the wrong solution when you down vote :(

Comment: No clue why people downvoted it. This is the correct answer (I'm the owner of the Win10 notification features).

Comment: I like the answer, was curious myself, and I'm discouraged as to why the question and answer was down voted as well as why it was marked `too broad`. Some of the people with power on this site are abusing it. This is frustrating.  Thank you for the question up top and thank you for the answer here.

Comment: i am replying on the comment after two years i know it's too late but i am writing this comment just to tell you that, your solution is perfect and working and to motivate you and tell you that you wasn't wrong. Cheers . .Happy new year by the way

Comment: haha thanks :) appreciated. Happy new year

Comment: Is it just for toast notifications? @DaveSmits

Comment: This is a link-only answer - if the link dies, the answer contains no useful information. See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/284827) or [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/284827) for more information.