# How to get all unread windows notification messages using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How to read all the windows notification messages using .NET? Also how to change the notification status to read or hide?

[image]

Comment: What are unread windows notification messages? Are you talking about winapi [WM_NOTIFY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-notify)? What kind of project do you have (winforms, wpf, etc.)?

Comment: ...adding to Sinatr's comment, do you mean the Windows 8/10 style notifications?

Comment: All the notification messages when I click the notification icon in the windows tray.

Comment: Imagine if programs could access this list and keep pushing their own messages and/or hide messages from other programs that they deem "less useful". I strongly suspect there's no API access because MS learned a lot from their experience with the notification area.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Windows 10 Toast Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51414815/c-sharp-windows-10-toast-notifications)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the content of a Windows 10 ?Notification in a UWP/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095140/how-can-i-get-the-content-of-a-windows-10-notification-in-a-uwp-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I capture toast notifications send from other processes in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781367/how-do-i-capture-toast-notifications-send-from-other-processes-in-windows-10)

Comment: @OlivierRogier

All the above 3 l links are related to windows mobile notifications, not desktop application.

Comment: @SukeshChand No. But the new Windows 8/10 notification system is [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform_apps), so you should have to use this new API system. This is not Win32 at all... Thus you need to reference particular [assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications) for that, only supported on Win8/10.